# PHP Update: check if serialnr already exists in database returns Yes > Can't update

Tags: php, for-loop, sql-update, exists

I just wrote this code until I realized that I won't be able to update a field without changing the serialnr to something which doesn't exists.

```
if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $errormsg = "";
    $errorcontrol = "
                SELECT serialnr
                FROM item
                WHERE serialnr='$_POST[serialnr]'
                ";
    $result=mysql_query($errorcontrol);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $errormsg= "<p id='notification'>Duplicate entry set.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        $UpdateQuery = "
                    UPDATE item SET 
                    itembrand='$_POST[itembrand]', serialnr='$_POST[serialnr]', itemname='$_POST[itemname]', itemgroupid='$_POST[itemgroupid]', addinfo='$_POST[addinfo]'
                    WHERE itemid='$_POST[itemid]'
                    ";
        mysql_query ($UpdateQuery)  ;
    }
}
```

If I would use this code for the "ADD NEW" section, it would work fine: don't add when it already exists.

But how can I do the update when the serialnr already exists?

Comment: Please use the search. You're not the first one with this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for the below lines needs to be, you missed the quotes in the `$_POST` keys,

```
 1.    $errorcontrol = "
            SELECT serialnr
            FROM item
            WHERE serialnr='$_POST['serialnr']'
            ";



2.     $UpdateQuery = "
                UPDATE item SET 
                itembrand='$_POST['itembrand']', serialnr='$_POST'[serialnr']', itemname='$_POST[itemname]', itemgroupid='$_POST['itemgroupid']', addinfo='$_POST['addinfo']'
                WHERE itemid='$_POST['itemid']'
```

Comment: With the quotes set I get error. My php want's it without the quotes. Perhaps version difference? Anyway, the query is working. I just need another method to check for existance. Not to check if it already exist, but check if it would exist twice after the update or something like that. That way it allows me to update information of an untouched serialnr. Any idea maybe?

Comment: what's the primary key for the table `item`?

Comment: oohk, any reason why you want to update the record, and then check if the `serialnr` already exists twice, rather than just check, if it exists and update if it doesnt?

Comment: cause, that leads to unnecessary (extra) queries. its not a good practice to clog the DB.

Comment: Because for example I have serialnr: 100, itembrand: Canon and when I update itembrand to Canon2 and keep serialnr on 100, it won't allow to update because serialnr 100 already exists. That's why I some other way.